# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-stomp'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket

I am trying to install react-stomp and getting this error

```
npm install --save react-stomp
```

**Error:**

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-stomp'.

How Can I fix this error?

**Resources:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stomp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're getting this when trying to install then you might have an internet issue or a packaging issue.

If you are absolutely sure you have access to the internet then maybe try to add this

```
 "react-stomp": "^5.1.0",
```

into your package.json then:

1. make sure to save
2. in terminal `npm install` or `npm i`

else if you're getting this when trying to use the module, make sure you are importing it correctly (might need to npm i -g)